# Jquery toggle issue using jquery ui effect

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to toggle a search bar.

```
    $(".search_button").click(function() {
        $("#search").toggle("bounce", {direction: "up"}, 150);
    });
```

Also i'm hidding the search bar by clicking anywhere on the screen with this code

```
    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {
        var container_search = $("#search");

        if ( ! container_search.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container_search.has(e.target).length === 0) // nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container_search.hide("drop", {direction: "up"}, 400);
        }
    });
```

Issue is that by implementing this above code toggle doesn't work. it's just doing show the search bar every time i click. it hides the bar then show it again. . . only i can hide the bar by just click  outside of the search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead, using one handler and toggling based on conditions.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).is('.search_button') ) {

        $("#search").toggle("bounce", {direction: "up"}, 150);

    }else if ( $(e.target).closest('#search').length === 0 ) {

        $("#search").hide("drop", {direction: "up"}, 400);
    }
});
```